# loading google maps in windows phone 8.1 using webview

Tags: javascript, google-maps, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a sample app to load google maps in windows phone 8.1. Using the webview approch I'm not able to launch google maps, please help me in fixing this.. Below is the code:

default.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Maps</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<!-- At runtime, ui-themed.css resolves to ui-themed.theme-light.css or ui-themed.theme-dark.css 
based on the user’s theme setting. This is part of the MRT resource loading functionality. -->
<link href="/css/ui-themed.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- Maps references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Google Maps API on Windows phone 8.1</h1>
<x-ms-webview id="Map" src="ms-appx-web:///map.html" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></x-ms-webview>
</body>
</html>
```

maps.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>


<script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- map references -->
<link href="/map.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
<script src="/map.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
<div id="mapdisplay" height="500px" width="500px"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

maps.js:

```
var map;
var dataResults;

function initialize() {   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdisplay'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -187.3),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});
addMarkers();
}

eqfeed_callback = function (results) {
   dataResults = results;
}

function addMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dataResults.features.length; i++) {
    var quake = dataResults.features[i];
    var coors = quake.geometry.coordinates;
    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(coors[1], coors[0]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLong,
        map: map
        //icon: getCircle(earthquake.properties.mag)
    });
   }
 }

 function getCircle(magnitude) {
  return {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: .2,
    scale: Math.pow(2, magnitude) / Math.PI,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: .5
  };
 }
```

What's the mistake I'm doing in the above code, please let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"maps.html" does not work because of multiple synchronicity issues.

1. Load `maps.js` before`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` so `initialise` is defined,
2. Load  `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js`and after the HTML has been parsed so the `mapdisplay` element exists when `initialise` is called.
3. Call `addMarkers` from `eqfeed_callback` not `initialise` so `dataResults` has been set with valid object data.

Most of this could have been found out by opening the developers console and checking it for errors when viewing "maps.html" in a desktop browser. You may also like to research other questions on the topic and/or check the api documentation for working examples - and notice how the api documentation uses `defer` and `async` attributes on the script tag to make sure it doesn't execute until after the page has been parsed.